# Jquery Set Image Dimension Attributes - Css Resized Images.

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, webkit

I am using twitter bootstrap responsive while scales images using css. 
For example images have a 100% width and then their heights are auto.

The problem is WebKit cannot handle the animations (specifically page scrolling) when images are without dimenensions.

How would i code a jquery function to run at the start of the page which does this:
For Each Image, get its actual on screen image size and then set the image attributes to those values?

Comment: Please post relevant code and create jsfiddle

Comment: Cant post a JS fiddle of a complete site.  We have a 1 page site which scrolls for aroudn 10,000 pixels,   If you google WebKit choppy animations you can see the bug has been reported with webkit many times.

Comment: Without looking at the code or a test page its hard to help

Comment: The question is very simple. 
Jquery EACH function get the current visible size of each image and then set that images attributes to those dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the dimensions and set them using jQuery .css()

```
$('.your-img').each(function(){
var img = $(this);
//get dimensions
var h = img.height();
var w = img.width();

//apply dimensions
img.css({
'width': w,
'height': h
});
});
```

Comment: can you target images without a class .your-img

Comment: you can target with the 'img' selector but that will select all the <img> tags.
`$('img')`